# Перемещение ползунка Slider в пределах SelectionStart и SelectionEnd

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть два элемента управления `Slider`:

```
<Slider x:Name="sBegin" Value="1000" Minimum="1000" Maximum="5000" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" SelectionEnd="{Binding Value, ElementName=sYearEnd}" SelectionStart="2005" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Ticks="1000,2000,3000,4000,5000/>
<Slider Name="sEnd"  Value="1000" Minimum="1000" Maximum="5000" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" SelectionStart="{Binding ElementName=sYearBegin, Path=Value}" SelectionEnd="5000" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Ticks="1000,2000,3000,4000,5000/>
```

Как настроить `Slider` чтобы нельзя было переместить ползунок за пределы `SelectionStart` и `SelectionEnd`

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно это: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/RangeSlider

Comment: Контрол хороший, но если бы был один `Slider` с заданными `SelectionStart` и `SelectionEnd`, значения которых внутри максимума и минимума, то возможно ли настроить ползунок, что бы он бегал в заданных пределах?

Comment: Решил проблему обработкой события `ValueChanged` у `Slider`. Если ползунок заходит за выделенные рамки, принудительно возвращаю значение в диапазон.

Comment: Можно, но придется писать контрол практически полностью, я вчера немного покопался в исходниках стандартного Slider и не придумал как можно с помощью наследования или т.п. сделать это

Comment: @АндрейNOP, у меня уж не такая задача, что бы контрол писать, через обработку событий вполне устраивает. Спасибо.